# How to move the menu vertical align of the grey bar

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to move the menu wordings align vertical on the grey bar, please see the attachment.

http://i1127.photobucket.com/albums/l622/sugarboylovephoto/ScreenShot2013-05-21at124323PM_zps317fe22f.png

This is the html code of the menu bar

```
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div class="head-padding"></div>
        <div id="head"><img src="images/head01.png" width="1010" height="106"></div>

        <div id="nav" class="navbgimg"> 
            <a href="#about" class="mid">About</a>
            <a href="#studying">Studying Science</a>
            <a href="#SSCI">About SSCI</a> 
            <a href="#highlights">Programme Highlights </a> 
            <a href="#life">Student Life</a> 
            <a href="#fun">Fun Fact</a> 
            <a href="#tips">Interview Tips</a>  </div>
            <div id="headwhite"><img src="images/head02.png" width="1010" height="20"></div>

        </div>

        <div id="page-wrap">
            <a name="about"></a>
            <div id="page1">
```

And this is the css code for the menu

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:160px; 
    width:100%;
}

#head {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#2848ad; 
    height:106px; 
    width:1010px;
}

.navbgimg {
    background-image: url(../images/menubar01.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1010px;
    height:34px; 
    letter-spacing: 0.1em
}

#nav {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    height:34px; 
    width:1010px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav a { padding-right: 20px; display:inline-block; }

#headwhite {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:150px;
    height:20px; 
    width:1010px;
}

#page1 {
    position:relative;
    top:150px;
    height:390px;
    width:1010px;
    background:#00c9e5;
}
```

Comment: I would more clear if you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to mark up a menu like this with an unordered list (`<ul>`). As noted, a working example would have been better. Anyhow, given what you have, you could try something like this:

```
#nav a {line-height: 34px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

set line-height:34px; in #nav like:

```
#nav {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    height:34px;
    line-height:34px; /*vertically align the text inside nev*/
    width:1010px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem. However you can check out this page to know how line-height property works.
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-text.php